# if is_post to affect only all posts not pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, html, if-statement

I'm using WordPress 3.5.1. I have put a litlle picture in the bottom of each page excluding a few by  is_page('') if statement in footer.php 
When i write in the is_post condition it removes the pictures from all the pages too!

Is there a way to exclude this picture only from all posts?

Tried is_single to no avail...

Hope you cold help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. But for instance, if you'd like to put a picture on every page that is of post_type page, you could do it as follows:

```
<?php if (is_page()): ?>
<img src="image_source" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Doing is_page('') will probably not work, as it will search for a page with an empty title or slug.

Comment: Actually i want quite the opposite - i would like it to display on every "page"  but disable it from "posts"

Comment: I could put a post id but i want it to apply for all posts

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting here, and what my code snippet is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using is_single instead.